# Regular expression (/<(\w+)\s+(.*?)>/) need improvement

Tags: regex, perl

There is a sub to handle the Type and Value.

```
sub parse_type_value_specifier { 
    my $tvs = shift; 
    my ($type, $value) = $tvs =~ /<(\w+)\s+(.*?)>/;
    return $type, $value; 
}
```

It should suit for three formats below.

```
<B 0> - works, return $type = (B) and $value = (0)
<A[1..80] ""> - doesn't work, need return $type = A[1..80] and $value = () # empty
<A[1..80] "hello"> - doesn't work. need return $type = A[1..80] and $value = (hello)
```

`/<(\w+)\s+(.*?)>/`   Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should specify your requirements a little more. What exactly do you want to allow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
/<([\w\[\].]+)\s*"?([^">]*)"?>/
```

or `/<(\w+)\s*"?([^">]*)"?>/` if your A[1..80] means \w length 1 to 80

Comment: This would also allow `<foo ">` or `<foo >"` or `<foo ">"`.

Comment: Yeah Gumbo, very correct, since we partially matching "?, I will add another one

Comment: @Gumbo. As you said, my A[1..80] means \w length 1 to 80. thank you.

Comment: I have changed `\s+` to `\s*` to match `<A[1..80]>`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/<(\w{1,80})\s*(?:\s([^\s">]+|"[^"]*"))?>/
```

Now if the match of the second grouping starts with a `"`, remove it from the start and the end and you have the plain value.

Answer (score 2):

The following "works" for the input you show but you should provide a more complete spec:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    if ( my ($type, $value) = /^<([A-Z])(?:\[.+\])?\s+"?(\w*)"?>/ ) {
        print "\$type = $type\t\$value = $value\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
<B 0>
<A[1..80] "">
<A[1..80] "hello">
```

Output:

```
$type = B       $value = 0
$type = A       $value =
$type = A       $value = hello
```

Comment: Hi Sinan, You teached me a good way to do some simple regex practice. Thank you.

Comment: btw, Why could the **__DATA__** segment be input to `while (<DATA>)` ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to ignore `"`s. Run it through another regex to strip those out first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<(.+) +"?(.*?)"?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is 99% correct, problem is that `\w` will not match literal square braces []. just repace \w with a  suitable character class `[\w\[\]\.]+`

```
<([\w\[\]\.]+)\s+(.*?)>
```